# Accessing Many key:value pairs from AWS lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, config

Im working on one project where I need to access many individual values in loop from my lambda Function ....I know that we can make use environment variables but I cannot create environment variable for all values and call it in loop so please advice whether can we use any file that contains all my values and call it in loop or any other way ? and Im using python 3.9 for lambda creation

Thanks in advance

Comment: AWS [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) seems like an excellent use case for this. You can store as many key-value pairs as you want and even encrypt the values using KMS if needed. I'd also recommend looking into Secrets Manager in case you have a ton of key-value pairs and need to ensure they're all encrypted for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to Access and update many key-value pairs by storing and accessing from AWS Secret store

Create the key:value pairs in AWS Secret store and we can access our key values from lambda where we need to mention our ARN of AWS secret store in Lambda environment variable and call it by importing os module

Its working perfectly and I can able to update the values by using 'client.update_secret'

We need to make sure that our Lambda execution role should have the permissions to GET,LIST,UPDATE...etc for the AWS Secret store service

Find the script below:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import os

session=boto3.session.Session()
client=session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name='<enter our region name>')



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    arn_v=os.environ['<enter our environment varaible name here... which contains the ARN of our secret store>'].split(',')
    for i in arn_v:
        try:
            get_secret_value_response=client.get_secret_value(SecretId=i)
            value1=eval(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])['<enter our key1 name>']
            value2=eval(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])['<enter our key2 name>']
            value3=eval(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])['<enter our key3 name>']
            print(get_secret_value_response)
            print(value1)
            print(value2)
            print(value3)
            
        except ClientError as e:
            raise e
```